# Record vs. recording

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

I have recorded someone's blood pressure over a period of one hour. Should the resulting file that contains the blood pressure samples be called *record* or *recording*?

http://physionet.org/physiobank/database/mimicdb/ uses the term *recording*:

> The database described below was the product of our first attempt
>   (1992-1999) to build a collection of multi-parameter *recordings* of ICU
>   patients.

However, I read in http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/record that *record* can mean:

> a collection of related items of information (as in a database)
>   treated as a unit

Shall I infer that I can interchangeably use both *record* or *recording* to designate the my file that contains the blood pressure samples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are specifically referring to *someone's blood pressure over a period of one hour* (the chart itself), that would be a *recording*. This is data collected over a period of time.
As in your example, I suppose you could refer to multiples here as *recordings* as long as you are referring to the data itself.

However, the paper strip itself could also be called a *record* (same as any test result). More than one would be *records*.

> I would like to check my medical **records**.

Disclaimer: Medical terminology may differ.

Comment: Thanks: could I call the file "record" as well, or should it be called recording all the time?